# I can't present ViewController in UIView

Tags: swift, uiview, presentmodalviewcontroller

**Flow:**

1. AViewController(modal on `MainViewController`)

   - FooView(Cell click) -> This view is like `cell`

     - BViewController -> modal on `AViewController`

I want `BViewController` to be present when I click on `FooView` in `AViewController`.

`AViewController` is presenting with `modal`.
`BViewController` is presenting with `modal`.

I want to present a nested modal.

Since `FooView` is a `UIView`, I created a protocol inside `FooView`. I trigger the function in the `protocol` with the button in the `FooView` and call this function in the `AViewController`. I want the function running in `AViewController` to `present` `BViewController` in `AViewController`, but I am facing this error.

**Error:**

**Thread 1: "-[ProjectName.`BViewController` _mutableLayoutGuides]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8d97b892e0"**

**AViewController:**

```
class AViewController: PresentableFilterPageForItemPage {

...
  
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

...
    
  }
  
  func presentFilterPageForItemPage() {
    let vc = FilterItemsVC()
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
  }
  
  func updateFilterItems(facets: [Facet]) {
    
    for item in facets {
      let filterItem = FooView() // <--- FooView here
      filterItem.titleLabel.text = item.definition
      filterItem.subTitleLabel.text = "Tümü"
      filterItem.delegate = self
      filterItemStackView.addArrangedSubview(filterItem)
    }
  }
}
```

**FooView:**

```
protocol PresentableFilterPageForItemPage: AnyObject {
  func presentFilterPageForItemPage()
}

class FooView: UIView {
  
  var buttonView: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTappedButton), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
  }()
  
  var delegate: PresentableFilterPageForItemPage?
  
  override func setupAfterInit() {
    
  }
  
  @objc func didTappedButton() {
    delegate?.presentFilterPageForItemPage()
  }
}
```

**BViewController**

```
class BViewController: UIViewController {

...
  
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
  }

  
  func updateFilterItems(facets: [Facet]) {
    
    for item in facets {
      let filterItem = FooView()
      filterItem.titleLabel.text = item.definition
      filterItem.subTitleLabel.text = "Tümü"
      filterItemStackView.addArrangedSubview(filterItem)
    }
  }
}
```